# how to turn off summernote editor focus

Tags: summernote

I have a form which contains many inputs. The last input is textarea tag linked to summernote editor.

the problem is, when the page load, it takes me to the bottom of the page, to the textarea tag.
I set sunnmernote focus to false. but nothing change.

how can load the page normally without moving to the textarea tag at the bottom of the page?

here is the js I'm using :

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.summernote').summernote({
            tabsize: 2,
            height: 100,
            focus: false,
            bold:false,
            fontNames: ['Tajawal', 'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Courier New'], 
            fontNamesIgnoreCheck: ['Tajawal']
        });
        $('.summernote').summernote('fontName', 'Tajawal');

    });
```

Comment: I solved it by adding focus to the main DIV when the page load

<script>
 window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("div").focus();
 };
</script>

after using tabindex="0" with the DIV

Answer (score 1):

remove the class called `summernote` in html `<textarea>` tag